# Trouble with lossy conversion Python

Tags: python

I wrote a program with Python that is designed to find a formula describing a set of numbers. Anyway, this formula works pretty well with smaller numbers that "play nice" (for instance, it'll handle `[1, 5, 7, 4]` just fine). However, when you feed it anything too large (`[10, 42, 20, 42, 30, 42]`) it quickly throws an exception (`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`). Now, when I debug this, I find that I'm seeing a bit of lossy conversion to double (for this set of numbers, `nval` is, on the second iteration, -611.8000000000000001). This, of course, makes things go all wrong and recurse infinitely. Now, I realize that my program is probably crappy BEYOND the lossy conversion, and I'd love any tips you have on that too, but does anyone have any ideas on fixing this?

Code (as per @jonrsharpe's comment, this is as brief as I can make it without sacrificing readability):

```
import math

def getdeg(numlist, cnt):
    if allEqual(numlist):
        return (0, numlist[0]) 

    count = cnt
    templist = []
    for i in range(len(numlist) - 1): 
        templist.append(numlist[i+1] - numlist[i]) 
    count += 1
    if not allEqual(templist):
        return getdeg(templist, count)
    else:
        return (count, templist[0])

def allEqual(numlist):
    x = len(numlist)
    if x == 1:
        return True
    for i in range(x-1):
        if not (numlist[i] == numlist[i+1]):
            return False
    return True

def getTerms(numlist, terms, maxpower): 
    newtable = []
    power, fval = getdeg(numlist, 0)
    if maxpower == 0:
        maxpower = power
    terms.append(fval / float(math.factorial(power)))
    if not power == 0:
        for i in range(len(numlist)):
            nval = numlist[i] - (terms[maxpower - power] * ((i + 1) ** power))
            newtable.append(nval)
        return getTerms(newtable, terms, maxpower)
    return terms

def printeq(numlist):
    #numlist = [2, 8, 9, 11, 20]
    print("Coeff\tPower")
    x = getTerms(numlist, [], 0)
    topPow = len(x) - 1
    for i in range(len(x)):
        print(str(x[i]) + "\t" + str(topPow))
        topPow -= 1

printeq([10, 42, 20, 42, 30, 42])
```

Comment: If it's *"a bit lengthy"*, **you** should cut it down to [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, I cut out one method that allows you to input numbers, took out comments, and implemented the function so it won't work. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps you can improve the question?

Comment: Perhaps the `fractions` module would be useful to you. It can exactly represent any real number, no lossy conversion required.

Comment: @Kevin I had no idea that was a thing. Thanks! If you'd like to post that as an answer (although perhaps with a bit more detail) I'll gladly upvote it, if not accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `fractions` module would be useful to you. It can exactly represent any real number, no lossy conversion required. I don't quite understand what your code is doing, but I think you can incorporate fractions by putting `import fractions` at the top of your script changing a single existing line. Within `getTerms`,

```
terms.append(fval / float(math.factorial(power)))
```

becomes

```
terms.append(fractions.Fraction(fval,math.factorial(power)))
```

Then your program runs without crashing:

```
Coeff   Power
13/5    5
-139/3  4
932/3   3
-2900/3 2
20576/15        1
-662    0
```